# EFAULT: bad address in system call argument Error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, static

I built a Nodejs app with node-static module to handle the static files such as CSS, the external JS files and JSON files, but this "EFAULT: bad address in system call argument error"  happen everytimes it is loaded. Does anyone can help me with this issue?
I think something wrong with Http Header or the way I use the node-static modules is causing this error.

```
0|index  | { Error: listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument :::3300
0|index  |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
0|index  |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
0|index  |     at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
0|index  |     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\CodeTest\codest_3\index.js:224:8)
0|index  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
0|index  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
0|index  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
0|index  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
0|index  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
0|index  |     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NINENORTH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
0|index  |   code: 'EFAULT',
0|index  |   errno: 'EFAULT',
0|index  |   syscall: 'listen',
0|index  |   address: '::',
0|index  |   port: 3300 }
```

And this is JS code that causes error

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs');
const qs = require('querystring');
const path = require('path')
const static = require('node-static');
const internalIp = require('ip');
var template = require('./lib/template.js');
var file = new static.Server(__dirname);


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // Dont know why it causes occasional 404...
  file.serve(req, res);

  var myLocaIP = internalIp.address();
  if (req.url === '/') {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/', req.url);
    let extname = path.extname(filePath);
    let contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
      case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
      case 'css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
      case '.json':
        contentType = 'application/json';
        break;
      case '.jpg':
        contentType = 'image/png';
        break;
      case '.js':
        contentType = 'image/jpg';
        break;
      }

    // ============== Add Note Box ==========================================
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'note_txt.txt'), (err, data) => {
     notetxt=String(data);
    });


    // ============== create LISTs from JSON ==========================================

    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'data', 'url_list.json'), (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('There was an error reading the file!', err);
        console.log(error.code);
      }
      var list_a = '';
      var list_b = '';
      var list_c = '';
      var list_d = '';

      var obj = JSON.parse(data);

      list_a = appendItem(obj, 'listA', list_a);
      list_b = appendItem(obj, 'listB', list_b);
      list_c = appendItem(obj, 'listC', list_c);
      list_d = appendItem(obj, 'listD', list_d);

      var html = template.html(list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d, notetxt, myLocaIP);
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
      res.end(html, 'utf-8');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hello Ian. For people to be able to help, it is helpful if you can add the code that is the cause of your exception. Or else people will be guessing in the dark. Hope this helps.

Comment: Were you able to solve this bug? I have the same

Comment: There's no default in your case, but I noticed that you `'css'` extension should probably `'.css'`.

Who knows if that's at all your issue?